# How can I disable "Clear recent apps"?

Tags: recents-screen

I have never wanted to clear the apps from the recent apps list but this has happened to me numerous times. At first, I thought it was a bug that happened randomly. Then I found that just above the menu button on the screen is another button that clears all the apps. I have accidentally hit this when trying to switch between apps many times because the two buttons are so close to each other. It just happened again when my cat rubbed on my hand and the phone as I was using it, and managed to press menu/clear recent apps with his face.

I would accept instructions on any of the following as an answer:

- Remove the Clear Recent Apps button
- Move the Clear Recent Apps button somewhere harder to press
- Add a "confirm" dialogue to Clear Recent Apps
- Block the action within the OS

I'm currently using Android 5.0 and my phone isn't rooted.

[image: Recent Apps List]

The button is the one on the semi-transparent overlay at the bottom with a "menu" icon with a superimposed cross.

Comment: Without root, you can't do it.

Comment: Just install some other launcher like GO Launcher and see if it's present..